# Jquery Ajax call works well with Google Chrome, but not with Firefox

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Hy guys,
i'm making some test with jquery, in particular ajax call.

```
$('#jsonpbtn').click(function() {
        $('#text').html('AJAX Call executing......');
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/10010',
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data.city);
                $('#jsonparea').html(data.city);
                $('#text').html('Ajax Call ended');
            },
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            },

        });


    });
```

The json response is {city: "New York City", state: "New York" ,country: "US"}

Using google chrome everything function well, in fact $('#jsonparea').html(data.city) write New York City in the div area. with firefox i have some problem, in fact div area isn't written, calling alert(data.city) i have undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Supply a dataType to your ajax options to ensure jQuery detects the dataType properly.

```
$('#jsonpbtn').click(function() {
    $('#text').html('AJAX Call executing......');
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/10010',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: "json", // <---- HERE
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data.city);
            $('#jsonparea').html(data.city);
            $('#text').html('Ajax Call ended');
        },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        },

    });

});
```

Now, if your json is exactly as you posted above, you will get a parseError because it isn't valid JSON, though i suspect it actually is valid since it worked in chrome.